# Rails nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails noob here.  I am modeling a simple trivia app where questions will have 4 options, one of which is correct.  My classes are:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

I want every question to have exactly 4 options, and I want to initialize 4 options automatically after I initialize the parent question.  How can I accomplish that easily in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an after_create callback. You can do this by adding one line and one method.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  after_create :generate_options

  def generate_options
    4.times { |_| this.options << Option.new(..) }
    self.save!
  end
end
```

In the Option.new I'm assuming your going to pass in any variables necessary for creation.

Comment: You would also need to assign a `:question_id` attribute in the Option model in order to maintain the has_many relation.

Comment: I assume your mean at the database level, because in the this.options << Option.new it should pick up that you're assigning it to a specific question.

Comment: Without the question_id attribute in the Option model, there is no solid relation between the question and option records. It either has to be an attribute or a third model with the associated IDs (e.g. has_many, :through =>)

Comment: Shouldn't I initialize them before I create the question so that I can build a form containing the question text and the 4 options?  That seems like the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, your question said "after I initialize the parent question", so I was going by that. If you want to do it before, use a before_create and don't call save.